# Changing Rotation Value to Negatives

Tags: unity-game-engine

Anytime I attempt to change my rotation settings to a negative number they change to a posotive number greater than my negative.  For example, I want to change my X & Y rotation values to -30 & -60 respectively, but when I attempt such they are auto-changed to 329.999 & 300 respectively.  Is there an additional setting that I am missing to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-60 is exactly the same as 300; a full turn is 360 degrees.